# How to remove trailing slash in Web API routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a URL which has some id which can have multiple "." values in it(Like 1.1, 1.1.0 , 2.0.0.1) like this and I want to treat it as string only not decimal.

So these work perfectly fine when I put a trailing slash and I get a string value in Route Value Dictionary
https://root/myApp/Download/File/1.1/

https://root/myApp/Download/File/1.1.0/

But without slash :
https://root/myApp/Download/File/1.1

It redirects to https://root Url

**Route Config**

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I figured that the id parameter above, when I pass a normal integer it works. Eg:
https://root/myApp/Download/File/1

But when I pass a decimal value like "1.1" or "1.1.0" and **Without trailing Slash** it does not work and redirects to root path.
Can anyone explain why this may be happening and how to work without the trailing slash ?

Answer (score 1):

Send your Controller code, i need view your Action.

In my API i'm using Route decorator with string parameter to resolve similar problem.

Ex.:

```
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("download/file/{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]string id)
    {
        string[] stringArray = id.Split('.')
        ...
    }
}
```

I need more informations for correct help you.